# Put $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log k}{2^{k-1}}$ in to some closed form.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Respected All.

I was doing some work on evaluation of $\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{...}}}}$ where I found that if $\{a_n\}$ be the given sequence then 
$$\log a_n\longrightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log k}{2^{k-1}}$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. The problem is I am unable to figure out if the $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log k}{2^{k-1}}$ can be put in to some closed form.

Can anyone help me on this regard please?

Comment: I do not think it has a nice closed form in term of elementary functions. But you can express it in terms of the polylog functions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\sum_{k\geq1}k^{s}z^{k}=\textrm{Li}_{-s}\left(z\right)
 $$ where $\textrm{Li}_{s}\left(z\right)
 $ is the polylogarithm function. Then we have $$\sum_{k\geq1}\log\left(k\right)k^{s}z^{k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\textrm{Li}_{-s}\left(z\right)
 $$ then $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\log\left(k\right)}{2^{k-1}}=2\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\textrm{Li}_{-s}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|_{s=0}.
 $$